# Login using cookies is not working in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to make a login system based on cookies (not to sing out when the page closes or refreshed)

this is the code behind the Login.aspx.cs:

```
  string cmdText = "SELECT Username,Role FROM Login WHERE Username = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND Password = '" + TextBox2.Text + "'";

        string username = "";
        string role = "";
        using (SqlCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmdText, connectionstring))
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            connectionstring.Open();
            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();


            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                username = myReader["username"].ToString();
                role = myReader["role"].ToString();
            }

            myReader.Close();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                string script = "alert(\"Login successful!\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
                connectionstring.Close();

                //STORE userinfo into cookie,set cookie Expires 1 day more
                Response.Cookies["username"].Path = username;
                Response.Cookies["username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                Response.Cookies["username"].Path = "/";

                Response.Cookies["role"].Path = role;
                Response.Cookies["role"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                Response.Cookies["role"].Path = "/";



                if (role.Equals("admin"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");

                    Label1.Text = "admin";

                }

                if (role.Equals("doctor"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("doctor.aspx");
                    Label1.Text = "doc";
                }


                if (role.equals("patient"))
                {
                    Response.Redirect("patient.aspx");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                string script = "alert(\"Login Failed!\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script, true);
                connectionstring.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

but looks like I am having problems in redirecting to the page I want.
when I enter username and password for the role of admin. It says login successful but doesnt proceed to the admin page. 
Why is it so? Am I missing something?

For admin(and other pages) I use this code to read the cookies

```
            string role = "";
            string username = "";
            if (Request.Cookies["role"] != null)
            {
                  role = Request.Cookies["role"].Value;

            }

            if (Request.Cookies["role"] != null)
            { 
              username = Request.Cookies["username"].Value;
            }

            if (role == "patient ")
            { 
                //SET control visible=false if no right.
                Button1.Visible = false;
            }
```

and this to edit cookies after login and/or after the user sings out

```
    //create cookie
Response.Cookies["username"].Value =  Server.UrlEncode("abc");
Response.Cookies["username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies["username"].Path = "/";

//modify cookie value
Response.Cookies["username"].Value =  Server.UrlEncode("def");;
Response.Cookies["username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
Response.Cookies["username"].Path = "/";


//delete cookie value
//delete cookie infact is set Expires is past day   DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies["username"].Value = Server.UrlEncode("def");
Response.Cookies["username"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies["username"].Path = "/";

//checking if cookie exist and reading it.
 if (Request.Cookies["role"] != null)
                {
                      role = Server.UrlDecode(Request.Cookies["role"].Value);

   }
```

but looks like I am missing something which I am not understanding. I think the problem is at if function, here:

```
 if (role.Equals("admin"))
```

any suggestion? is this the right way to use cookies?

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? asp.net has all this functionality built-in already. And as your code is now it is very vulnerable to SQL injection and your cookies are probably not secure. Google `asp net authentication` or read this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/formsauthentication-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Are you getting any error messages for response.redirect?

Comment: @Balaji I cant reconnect to the page I want. according to the role(doctor) I am not being redirected to any page. it just stays there, at login page.

Comment: @VDWWD Much thanks. I will try to take a look at it. but can you please try to answer that not just comment, so I can put that as the answer?

Comment: are you able to debug it? either using VS or a javascript debug?

Comment: looks like the 'if' code is not working properly. I changed the alert pop-up to show the role. and it shows it correctly. but looks like I am missing something which I am not understanding with the 'if ( role.equals("admin"))' is not working like it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel? asp.net has all this functionality built-in already. And as your code is now it is very vulnerable to SQL injection and your cookies are probably not secure. Google `asp net authentication`

This simple tutorial can show you how to get started: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/syedshakeer/formsauthentication-in-Asp-Net/

You will also need to create a database for storing the user, passwords, roles etc. This article can help you with that: https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb

Also if you create a new Project in Visual Studio it will add a login form (and more) so you can use that as an example. File > New Project > Web > ASP.NET Web Application

Answer (score 1):

Im kind new to cookies too, but after googled for some hours, im using Cookies this way, and its working, hope it helps you
To Add Cookies:

```
string UserData = _User + "/" + _Password;
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1 , _User , DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60), _KeepLoggedIn, UserData);
string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
cookie.Name = "SESSION";

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

To read Cookies:

```
HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("SESSION");
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
                var userName = ticket.Name;
                var userData = ticket.UserData.Split('/').ToArray();

                string _User = userData[0];
                string _Password = userData[1];
                ... Your code to authenticate and 'Response.Redirect'...
             }
```

To 'Delete' Cookies:

```
int limit = Request.Cookies.Count; //Get the number of cookies and 
                                               //use that as the limit.
            HttpCookie aCookie;   //Instantiate a cookie placeholder
            string cookieName;

        //Loop through the cookies
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            cookieName = Request.Cookies[i].Name;    //get the name of the current cookie
            aCookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);    //create a new cookie with the same
                                                     // name as the one you're deleting
            aCookie.Value = "";    //set a blank value to the cookie 
            aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);    //Setting the expiration date
                                                           //in the past deletes the cookie

            Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie);    //Set the cookie to delete it.
        }
```